# Include current rewritten URI in substitution

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Without changing my patterns to match the whole string (which would make them a lot more complicated), is there a way to use the current URI in the substitution string?

Using `%{REQUEST_URI}` won't work, as that uses the original URI.

Comment: Why would it make them more complicated?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: I only mentioned it because I want an answer to the question, not for someone to suggest the work-around that I already know.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what I'm saying is that switching from something like..

```
RewriteRule ^/some/path/(.*)\.html$ /$1/
```

..to..

```
RewriteRule ^(/some/path/(.*)\.html)$ /$2/?fullurl=$1
```

..isn't really very burdensome.

The question you asked doesn't have a solution; there's no special variable that holds the string being matched against in `RewriteRule`, since you already have that string available to you.